# Convert image to base64 in HTML (C#)

Tags: c#, html, base64

Want to convert image to base64.

If I found img tag from HTML then that img tag convert into base64.

> INPUT : HTML with img with PATH
>
> OUTPUT : HTML with base64 image

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;">Test my Test my Test my Test my Test my Test my </span>
            <span style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;font-style: italic;">Test</span>
            <span><img src="Document_files/Image2.png" alt="\Desktop\javascript (1).png" width="160" height="96" border="0" /></span>
            <span><img src="Document_files/Image3.jpeg" width="173" height="103" border="0" /></span></p>
            <span style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;"> my Test my Test my </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no way to do this that doesn't smell awful. Why are you trying to do this? Do you have control over the source of this html?

Comment: Don't want to store image in server. all image convert to base64 and that store in table in database. Yes, I have store HTML in database. just need to update

Comment: So it's just a one-off update?

Comment: Yes, It is for only all img tag in HTML.

Comment: string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)); Then for your image tag, src="data:image/png;base64,{base64 goes here without these braces}". For jpeg files, it's image/jpeg. Or are you asking for more than this?

Comment: I have above HTML file. In HTML file, If found img tag then need to convert(Only img). and Replace this img tag to base64. After converted, If I run this HTML then I can see image.  I will be remove all image from server.

Comment: @J.H. has described the way to do it. Does that not meet your requirements?